# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object User.id

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, typeerror

I'm trying to register an new Transaction object on the DB using Django, but I'm having `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` when I try to do `user_id = user.id` I can't really understand why this is happening, since I do the same steps when registering a new Bank object (as shown on prints below). I've tried to debug and the local variables have the correct value, I've also tried to cast user.id with string or int, but none of them worked.
[traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6fc1.png) [console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/madMa.png) [create Transaction method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scIJK.png) [create Bank method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC4T4.png)
 [models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWv4H.png)

Comment: where is the problem comming from? post the traceback. Is it a migration problem?

Comment: I've edited the post, was having some issues on StackOverflow

Comment: @hansTheFranz I've added some links to check the traceback, thanks

Comment: Since you're using `pdb`, what does `type(user)` and `type(user.id)` give?  The traceback is telling you "I expect X or Y", which means `user.id` is neither.  Possibly related, you do `b.save` with no parentheses in `registerNewUser` second to last line.  That's an empty statement, it returns a function object that you never save.  You want to call the function with `save()`?

Comment: @sjm324 
(Pdb) type(user)
<class 'django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject'>
(Pdb) type(user.id)
<class 'int'>
I tried casting the user.id to str and it still throws TypeError

Comment: Hmmm.  Beyond my domain, unfortunately.  Maybe check what the `type` is of the working one.  The cause of the problem seems to actually be a different line, related to the class definition.  I don't know django well enough, but `SimpleLazyObject` sounds to me like they're doing some metaprogramming behind the scenes for you.  Likely one of the items you have declared in the class is incorrect, causing some form of trap state with the creation of the object?  Just a guess

Comment: I used to request.user (SimpleLazyObject) to get the User object from DB and even like this I still have the same error. I removed the parentheses on t.save and the error keeps on. I have no idea what else is causing this issue. I created the Transaction model exactly like I did to the Bank one. Initially I even tried to associate The Bank to the transaction, instead of the user and it was the first time I got TypeError, so I switched to User and haven't progressed since then

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please don't post code or errors as images; they are text, they should be posted as text in the question.

However I don't see anything in any of those snippets that suggest the error is with the user - that line is probably highlighted because it's the last in that multi-line call.

Rather, the error looks to be in the reference to `date.today` - if that's the `datetime.date` class, then `today` is a method, which you would need to call:

```
Transaction.objects.create(date=date.today(), ... )
```

Or, since that field has a default anyway, you could leave out the `date` attribute from the create call altogether.